# I am not able to assign the iterator (current_song = songs.begin();).No operator"=" match these operands

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
void play_next_song(const list<Song>& songs,list<Song>::iterator &current_song) {
cout << "playing next song " << endl;
if (*current_song == songs.back()) {
    playFirstSong(songs);
    current_song = songs.begin();
    return;
}
current_song++;
play_current_sound(current_song);
```

}
I am not able to assign the iterator (current_song = songs.begin();).No operator"=" match these operands

Comment: read the full error message, if you do not understand it no problem we can explain, but it should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since `songs` is a `const` reference, `songs.begin()` returns a `const_iterator`. You must declare `current_song` also as `const_iterator` because a `const_iterator` cannot be converted to a (non-const) `iterator`. (The conversion in the other direction is possible, though.)